# Amazon SQS queue Not sending mail on my id

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am working on laravel 4.2 and I am new with SQS queue,my code works fine also i can see my queues in aws console but it not sending mail on my email id "ibrar@whiterabbit.is". I am using mandrill for sending mail.

```
Mail::queue($template, $data, function($m) use ($data, $subject,   $admin_email, $site_title) {
  $m->from($admin_email, $site_title);
  $m->to("ibrar@whiterabbit.is", "ibrar@whiterabbit.is");
  $m->subject($subject);
  });
```

I also try that code but the problem is same, after Queue::push its not come in  Mail::send

```
Queue::push(function($job) use ($data) {
      Mail::send($template, $data, function($m) use ($data, $subject, $admin_email, $site_title) {
      $m->from($admin_email, $site_title);
      $m->to("ibrar@whiterabbit.is", "ibrar@whiterabbit.is");
      $m->subject($subject);
      });
    });
```

Comment: I think you have the SQS service confused with the SES service.

Comment: I think i should use php Listener after queue job.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion SQS is a simple queuing service and i use it for that like RabbitMQ for example. You can push an E-Mail to your queue but you have to process them.

To send an E-Mail you have to use SES. AT the moment you push your Mail to your queue but you don't send it.

SES is a simple Mail system you can send your mails over smtp directly to SES witch send your mail. But its possible that i didn't understand your question correctly.

Comment: When email comes in SQS queue then SES will come to know and send it to user email? Is it using beanstalk/Lamda or something else?

Comment: SQS don't send anything. You need something to process and send the message. For that you can use Lambda if you don't want to implement it in your main program.